# Android Studio SDK 27.1.0 CardView Render Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview

**Render problem**
Failed to find style 'cardViewStyle' in current theme   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

**Missing styles**
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.

Cardview render correctly in SDK 26.1.0,27.0.1,27.0.2

[image]
[image]

Comment: show your project gradle file...

Comment: I have the same issue. By the moment I am using 27.0.1 version. Android Studio is notifying me that **all the android support libraries have to use the same version** so if someone knows how to fix this I would appreciate that!

Comment: add this dependency `compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'`

Comment: As far as I know, this is a bug. Whole android department in my company is getting this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [failed to find style 'cardView Style' in current theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153215/failed-to-find-style-cardview-style-in-current-theme)

Comment: In my case Workaround 1 worked well: Here it is: [The best answer is already in the Stackoverflow:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49223152/6780216)

Answer (score 2):

Try converting gradle to this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

I had the same issue and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and therefore finally changed the card view from :27.1.0 to 26.1.0.

Try converting all support libraries as per my gradle and then sync it. See if it works?

[gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HztHm.jpg)

Comment: you can even use 27.0.2

Answer (score 0):

for whoever came here and spent so much time on figuring out what to do, Just download [Android Studio Canary](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/) then extract use this [**Tutorial**](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview) to install it along-side the other version you have and it will handle your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Update your Android Studio version with latest version and use SDK 28.