# failed to find style 'cardView Style' in current theme

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, rendering, android-support-library

After updating support library version `27.1.0` **Android Studio** unable to render CardView. It shows error message as

```
failed to find style 'cardView Style' in current theme
```

But no error in compiling and no difference while seeing on the phone.

I have reverted the support library version to `27.0.2` and it's rendering fine.

The issue with support library or **Android studio**? How to fix this?

**App Level Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tmmmt.tmmmt"
        minSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            buildConfigField 'String', 'FS_CLIENT_ID', FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_ID
            buildConfigField 'String', 'FS_CLIENT_SECRET', FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_SECRET
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            buildConfigField 'String', 'FS_CLIENT_ID', FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_ID
            buildConfigField 'String', 'FS_CLIENT_SECRET', FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_SECRET
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "default"
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', BASE_URL_DEV
            manifestPlaceholders = [GEO_API_KEY: GOOGLE_MAP_KEY_DEV]
        }

        beta {
            dimension "default"
            versionNameSuffix "-beta"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', BASE_URL_BETA
            manifestPlaceholders = [GEO_API_KEY: GOOGLE_MAP_KEY_BETA]
        }

        live {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', BASE_URL_LIVE

            manifestPlaceholders = [GEO_API_KEY: GOOGLE_MAP_KEY_LIVE]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$anko_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$play_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$play_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$play_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.tmmmt.library:arrowtab:1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:chatkit:0.2.2'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.16'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.16'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.16'
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:logger:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.tmmmt.library:animations:0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    /*Fort*/
    implementation project(':FortSDKv1.4.1')
    implementation 'com.victor:lib:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.8'
    implementation('com.nispok:snackbar:2.11.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0-android'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    /*Fort*/
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Project Level Gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.1'
    ext.support_version = '27.1.0'
    ext.play_version = '11.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.2"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://mymavenrepo.com/repo/eDGOo6Dqr4f6uNA0HoWX/"
            credentials {
                username = 'myMavenRepo'
                password = 'tmmmt123'
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Update:**

There is no such error from `Android Studio 3.2`. The error was gone completely.

Comment: show your gradle file

Comment: Gradle file updated @AbhinavGupta

Comment: For me the solution was to delete gradle cache and clean-rebuild the project.The problem was obviously in Gradle linking process with cached data.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Checking the source of `CardView` one can see that the constructor

```
public CardView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize(context, attrs, 0);
}
```

has been changed to

```
public CardView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.cardViewStyle);
}
```

And the new attribute `cardViewStyle` is defined in the library. I guess that the Android Studio preview is not including the value for this attribute from the library, for some reason. I'm not sure if it usually resolves custom attributes defined in libraries and this is a bug, or if this is intended.

**Workaround 1**

Resolve the attribute in your theme (maybe only in debug version), this way the error is gone. `@style/CardView` is already defined in the support library so you don't need to create the style, just reference it.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView</item>
</style>
```

Be sure to use `AppTheme` in the layout preview and clean build.

**Workaround 2**

Add the style with `tools` namespace so that it won't affect your production code. The rendering error will be logged, but you will see the `CardView` anyway

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    tools:style="@style/CardView"
    ...
```

**Good news**

Android Studio 3.1 seems to be handling this correctly, no workaround needed (the error in the layout preview is still logged though).

On Android Studio 3.2 (currently in Canary channel) the error is gone.

Comment: came here after updating to android studio 3.1, so for me its not fixed.

Comment: @Odys ok now I see, I didn't notice that the error in layout preview is still there, but, the CardView is rendered without workaround, are you having the same?

Comment: Your 1st suggestion is correct and removes the problem, which exists in Android Studio v3.1

Comment: @Odys I don't understand one thing, I'm using 3.1 now and I can see the CardView in the preview without the workaround, but I still see the error logged when clicking on `!`. Aren't you seeing the CardView at all on 3.1?

Comment: Yes I was but not correctly. I reverted to 3.0.1 after wasting half day. Thing is that lots of the designer stuff are broken. The designer, dagger, code suggestions, linter, maybe more..

Comment: @Odys thx for the info, I just tried 3.1 but at work we decided not to update yet, I guess it was a wise decision :)

Comment: @Mian.Ammar just out of curiosity, are you able to see the CardView without workaround? What I see on AS 3.1.2 is that the error is logged in the preview, but I can see the CardView rendered

Comment: @lelloman yes card view is rendered with elevation and corner radius but inside content is not visible

Comment: work around 1 worked for me. i am using andriod studio 3.1.3

Comment: AAHHH I've had this problem for SO long. Workaround 1 worked for me, thank you very very much!

Answer (score 9):

I also had the same problem, so I added

```
<item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView</item>
```

in my styles.xml file. But it was showing a warning "The resource @style/CardView is marked as private in com.android.support:design".

So, after that I tried this one

```
<item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>
```

and this worked for me. I am using Android Studio 3.1.4 and Gradle 4.4.

Answer (score 4):

updating the `CardView` from [27.1.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/cardview-v7/27.1.1) to [28.0.0-alpha3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/cardview-v7/28.0.0-alpha3) fixed the XML preview for me on AS 3.1.3.

```
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3"
```

it still complains, but it renders the preview.

there's also a new [androidx](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor) class now, which should be the same:

```
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
```

when updating `com.android.support:design` to `28.0.0-alpha3`, it hints for:

```
The resource @style/CardView is marked as private in com.android.support:design
```

downgrading back to API 27 with buildTools 27.0.3 & supportLibrary 27.1.1 also prevents the issues. might upgrade to `28.0.0` with [Android Studio 3.2](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/06/android-studio-32-beta-2-available.html) then.

Comment: @Dev better migrate to `androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0` (which equals `28.0.0` final). these `alpha`, `beta` and `rc`version were never meant to be "stable".

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason of the error with CardView was because of the wrong listheader attribute of a child Spinner. Alongside the `failed to find style 'cardView Style' in current theme` error message I got `Spinner adapter view type count must be 1`, so the roots of the CardView failing were surprisingly in Spinner rendering failure.