# Failed to find style 'floatingActionButtonStyle' in current theme

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm newbie to android development so i start the simple project that came with android studio "hello world " but it give this problem :

**Failed to find style 'floatingActionButtonStyle' in current theme** 
I have android studio 3.1.3 x86

also my SDK Version from the build.gradle file  is  28

and this is the **activity_main.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is my **content_main.xml**:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: There are some lags in AS sometimes. Did you try to synchronize and rebuild your project? Tap "Gradle"  on the right pane and press on a blue "syncing" icon. Then, go to Build -> Rebuild Project on top menu of the Android Studio. It should help.

Comment: i have try it but nothing change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking the source of `FloatingActionButton` one can see that the constructor has been changed to

```
public FloatingActionButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.floatingActionButtonStyle);
}
```

There's new `floatingActionButtonStyle` which seems not included by default in `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'`

The best workaround I found (based on similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153215/failed-to-find-style-cardview-style-in-current-theme)) is to define the attribute in your theme (maybe only in debug version), this way the error is gone as `@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton` is already defined in the support library so you don't need to create the style, just reference it inside your `AppTheme` style in your `values/styles.xml` file.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton</item>
</style>
```

Be sure to use AppTheme in the layout preview and clean build.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a "false" error about the style: check if you the `setOnClickListener` writed for the correct activity where you have this issue. Maybe you've writed the listener for this button to the wrong activity. You can easily test it by comment temporarely the code about `setOnClickListener` and re-launching the build..